# Gravity forms API shows 404 error

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity forms API in Wordpress 4.9.4 but when I am calling gravityforms API via URL its showing me error 404.

Here is one of the example link that I am trying to call.

https://example.com/gravityformsapi/forms/?api_key=xxxxxx&signature=xxxxx&expires=xxxxx

But it's giving me 404 error. My Gravity forms plugin version is 2.2.5.

Is anybody got same kind of error & solved it?

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution?